# Is it possible to connect USB printer to Atmega8

Tags: usb, atmega, usb-device, interface, usb-host

I have a usb thermal printer, that I want to control using Hex commands in its datasheet from cheap micro-controllers. But to do that I need to create USB host in my board and it requires more than just Atmega8. Instead If I just throw usb packet, which has my command, from controller to printer, would it work?

Comment: Simply put NO. USB is a complex bidirectional protocol. Having something just yell packets at a device won't work.

Comment: if you have already interfaced some USB slaves, you should be able to do it.

Comment: @Umar no, that's not true. USB will not work by "just throwing USB packets" in one direction.

Comment: What if I use RS232 to USB converter?

Comment: @MarcusMüller what I meant is, if OP was able to interface to trigger slaves such as Pen drives, mouse, keyboard etc.. Then person is already comfortable in using USB interface.

Comment: unfortunately I've never done that before @Umar

Comment: You can also share datasheet of USB thermal printer. Basically, to understand the cimmand set.

Comment: RS232-USB converters act as USB  devices. You need a USB host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB is a particularly complex and timing-sensitive protocol which is not conducive to bit-banging on a microcontroller. Even attempting to manually implement the USB state machine in an FPGA from the ground up would be a significant amount of work, involving deep knowledge of the USB specification and practical implementation quirks.

You'll need an external USB host IC, or a microcontroller with inbuilt USB host support.

Comment: Note that microcontrollers with USB support are relatively cheap these days. Typically cheaper than atmegas. Also, note that for 32bit microcontrollers that are faster than an atmega, but a lot cheaper, slow (as in: USB HID) bitbanging implementations as *slave* [exist](https://media.ccc.de/v/33c3-8031-no_usb_no_problem) (but that doesn't help you the least when implementing a USB host, as OP wants).

Comment: What If I use RS232 to USB converter?

Comment: @BilguunCH Those are (generally) not host devices.

Comment: @BilguunCH A RS232 to USB converter needs to be a device – USB isn't a point-to-point thing without setup (like a simple serial line), the USB host must say to what it wants to talk to, assign bus addresses and do a lot more stuff. Really, if you want to operate an USB device on a USB Bus from a USB Host, you'll need to use a device that can work as USB Host. Period. Ditch the ATMega. Get some cheap ARM Cortex-M0 that has a USB Host interface integrated.